# Administrative divisions of Cambodia

Tags: asia, cambodia

Where can I find an official list with hierarchical relationship between various levels of the administrative division in Cambodia?

Comment: have you searched https://opendevelopmentcambodia.net/?

Answer (score 1):

If this is what you are looking for then here it is

http://www.gadm.org/download